# Executing shell commands from Scala REPL

Tags: scala

An interesting feature of Scala REPL is if you drop any jar in your `%SCALA_HOME%\lib` directory, it is available for import from the REPL. I have several jars there, and I often need to find out which ones are available to be included. So I always have to open another command window and find out which jars exist in that directory. It would be great if the REPL allowed me to execute system commands such as `dir` or `ls` or at least list all the jars in the above lib directory. What is the easiest way (if any) to invoke shell commands in REPL ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In REPL the `:sh` command allow you to introduce shell command:

Windows version:

```
scala> :sh cmd /C dir
  res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult = `cmd /C dir` (28 lines, exit 0)
scala> res0 foreach println
```

(unfortunately, there is no way to avoid the call to `cmd \C` before the shell command)

Unix-like version:

```
scala> :sh ls
  res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult = `cmd /C dir` (28 lines, exit 0)
scala> res0 foreach println
```

**Update:** Inspired by [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9895339/1730), a little trick for windows user:

```
scala> implicit def stringToDosProcess(s: String) =
  scala.sys.process.stringToProcess("cmd /C "+ s)
stringToDosProcess: (s: String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder

scala> "dir".!
```

Comment: Thanks! this is closest to what I was looking for.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows:

Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121). Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

```scala
scala> :sh cmd /C dir

res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult = `cmd /C dir` (27 lines, exit 0)


scala> res0 foreach println

<console>:13: error: value foreach is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult
       res0 foreach println
            ^
```

Comment: Try res0.lines foreach println.

Comment: toDos, haha! :)

Answer (score 18):

Alternative: use Scala's `sys.process` library:

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "ls /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final".!
bin
doc
lib
man
meta
misc
src
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: cool but not so great in windows, as "dir", etc (and most useful commands) are not separate files but embedded in the shell interpretter.

Comment: I've updated my answer to build something as tasty as this for windows users

Comment: @Jus12 Use `cmd` for them. The question was about executing shell commands from REPL, the actual problem was listing files. I gave one solution for each. :-)

Comment: Yes I agree. The problem is with Windows. Both your answers are very useful though.

Comment: looks like for non-builtin commands you have to use `Seq("cmdname", "arg1", "arg2")` to be able to pass in arguments.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

The means for extracting `:sh` output has changed over the years.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :sh date
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult = `date` (1 lines, exit 0)

scala> res0 foreach println
<console>:13: error: value foreach is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult
       res0 foreach println
            ^

scala> res0.show
<console>:13: error: value show is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult
       res0.show
            ^

scala> res0.lines
res3: List[String] = List(Sat Sep 17 19:29:26 PDT 2016)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little-known trick of REPL:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-20120323-101508-45eebcf98d (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/<TAB>
/home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/misc   /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/bin    /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/man    /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/src    /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib    
/home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/meta   /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/doc    

scala> /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/<TAB>
/home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-dbc.jar        /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-swing.jar      /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/jline.jar            
/home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-library.jar    /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-compiler.jar   /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scalap.jar           

scala> /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-library.jar
res0: scala.tools.nsc.io.File = /home/dcs/scala-2.9.1.final/lib/scala-library.jar
```

Where `<TAB>` is I pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: you can REPL insert <TAB> everywhere, "/ho<TAB>/dcs/scala-2.9<TAB>", or at least on Linux that's the case

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2018/01/15**

Example: you like to see the files in the current working directory:

```
scala> :sh ls -l
res3: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult = `ls -l` (13 lines, exit 0)
```

But you can't do this:

```
scala> res3.foreach {println}
<console>:40: error: value foreach is not a member of scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProcessResult
       res3.foreach {println}
            ^
```

First you have to assign the lines to another type that supports iteration:

```
scala> res3.lines
res7: List[String] = List(total 960, -rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff   11325 Jan  3 15:01 LICENSE, -rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff    8859 Jan  3 15:01 README.rst, drwxr-xr-x@  3 dave  staff      96 Jan  3 15:03 assembly, drwxr-xr-x@ 20 dave  staff     640 Jan  3 15:01 bin, drwxr-xr-x@ 13 dave  staff     416 Jan  3 15:01 doc, drwxr-xr-x@  7 dave  staff     224 Jan  3 15:01 docker, drwxr-xr-x@  6 dave  staff     192 Jan  3 15:03 examples, -rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff     826 Jan  3 15:01 gradle.properties, -rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff     128 Jan  3 15:04 h2o_drivers.txt, drwxr-xr-x   3 dave  staff      96 Jan 16 00:54 h2ologs, drwxr-xr-x@  5 dave  staff     160 Jan  3 15:04 py, -rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff  455890 Sep 19 04:18 rsparkling.tar.gz)
```

Then iterate, and voila!

```
scala> res7.foreach {println}
total 960
-rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff   11325 Jan  3 15:01 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff    8859 Jan  3 15:01 README.rst
drwxr-xr-x@  3 dave  staff      96 Jan  3 15:03 assembly
drwxr-xr-x@ 20 dave  staff     640 Jan  3 15:01 bin
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 dave  staff     416 Jan  3 15:01 doc
drwxr-xr-x@  7 dave  staff     224 Jan  3 15:01 docker
drwxr-xr-x@  6 dave  staff     192 Jan  3 15:03 examples
-rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff     826 Jan  3 15:01 gradle.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff     128 Jan  3 15:04 h2o_drivers.txt
drwxr-xr-x   3 dave  staff      96 Jan 16 00:54 h2ologs
drwxr-xr-x@  5 dave  staff     160 Jan  3 15:04 py
-rw-r--r--@  1 dave  staff  455890 Sep 19 04:18 rsparkling.tar.gz
```