# Change Directory of the Spark-Shell (Windows Environment) for the session

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I want to change my current directory within the scala REPL.

I applied the "stringToDosProcess solution" from [Executing shell commands from Scala REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886123/executing-shell-commands-from-scala-repl) to execute commands. I am able to execute commands such as `dir`.

I have a sub directory called lab1. Once I use: `"cd lab1".!`, I get a result such as: res7: Int = 0, but I am still in the same directory.

It seems to be a scope problem as I get a "The system cannot find the path specified" once I use a non existing directory as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to REPL system commands with :sh, or play with System.properties, i do not recommend this like shuggest [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5164)

If not you can apply commands to any dir with this work around:

```
import sys.process._
import java.io.File

val output = Process("ls -al", new File("/tmp")).!!
  println(output)

val p = Process("ls -al") //in your directory
```