# How to execute system commands in scala

Tags: scala, cmd

i am new at scala and i am trying to run this simple program that get input from the user and execute it in the operation system:

```
import scala.io._ 
import sys.process._

object MyCmd {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
      print("> ")
      var inputString = StdIn.readLine()

      while(!inputString.trim().equals("exit")) {
        var proc = stringToProcess(inputString)
        println( proc.!!)
        print("> ")
        inputString = StdIn.readLine()
     }
  }
}
```

but when i'm running it:

```
c:\IDE\scala\test>scala MyCmd
> dir
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The
system cannot find the file specified
...
```

Any help will be much appreciate

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Copy pasting this code works for me. Which Scala version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

sys.process.ProcessBuilder not runnig Windows cmd command.

See [Executing shell commands from Scala REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886123/executing-shell-commands-from-scala-repl)

If you need to use the cmd command, you can execute as

```
val proc = stringToProcess("cmd /C "+inputString)
println(proc.!!)
```

Comment: I've looked in many articles, none of them wrote anything about `cmd /C` nor `stringToProcess` that helped a lot. Thanks!